# Fastlane - How to add user to Testflight with Group?

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane

Am on FastLane , trying to setup iOS builds to Testglight - Am on the latest version - 2.88.0.

When i try to add an internal tester to iTunesConnect

> fastlane pilot add email@invite.com

I get an error

> ERROR: You must provide 1 or more groups (with the `:groups` option)

This is my part of the lane - the Pilot command

```
# upload to Testflight
pilot(skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
    email:"user@email.com",
    distribute_external: false)
```

Where do i provide these groups?
If i use the -g option, it says the groups don't exist?

Do i need to manually go to iTunesConnect and create a group?
That defeats the purpose of automating stuff.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: I manage members on iTunesConnect manually. After delivering app by `pilot`, those members will get notifications about new released app.

Comment: you set group as a param look this https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/#parameters

Answer (score 0):

Creating a group is usually just a "one-time" thing so its easiest to create your one or two groups in iTunesConnect directly and then reference those group names in `pilot`.

If you want to do it all programmatically though, you could use `spaceship` directly create a group with something like...

```
group = Spaceship::TestFlight::Group.create!(app_id: 'app-id', group_name: 'Group 1')
```

You may have to check if the group exists first so it doesn't error out. You could also create a separate lane for creating groups for this app so that you don't have to go into iTunesConnect to create any new groups.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Can i create a lane like this
lane :creategroup do
  group = Spaceship::TestFlight::Group.create!(app_id: 'app-id', 
      group_name: 'Group 1')
end

Comment: Or can i use an option to create groups using the pilot or upload_to_testflight alias?  I see no option in documentation.

Comment: How will fastlane know about Spaceship? Do we need to import something?